# .htaccess redirect loop when using rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this code to force `https` and redirect all the requests to `index.html` but the code is resulting in `Too Many Redirects`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

I've also tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But it makes URLs like `example.com/index.html/page/about`

Comment: Open Firebug and visit `https://example.com/` and see what redirects do you get in Net tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.html` is probably empty (0-size), and not recognized by `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s`.

Instead of, use `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` to check if your URL is a real file, whatever its size:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: the `index.html` is not empty. However, this is resulting in same error :(